# IBActions of UIButtons not responding after rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uibutton, ibaction

Note: My VCs are using Autoconstraints. I'm not sure why some buttons on my VCs are not responding after I rotate from landscape to portrait and vice versa.

I got a hunch that this has something to do with Autoconstraints, but got no idea how to prove it.

Not using any animations either.

Yes I assign IBActions properly and they all respond well if I lock on a single orientation, problem occurs when I start rotating my app.

Comment: Show us your code, *please*.

Comment: seems to have been answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739902/ios-change-auto-layout-constraints-when-device-rotates

Comment: @Neeku: A simple ViewController with simple IBActions all connected, no special code written I'm just using 'NSLogs();' to see if they will respond after I rotate my app. I use Interface Builder to make autoconstraints, no warnings or errors... and saddly, after any rotation events, no response from the IBActions. I got nothing special to show I assure that. ITS A PLAIN SIMPLE VC WITH CONNECTED IBACTIONS