# Changing Auto Layout constraints for orientation

Tags: ios, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I have an app that lays out differently depending on whether it's in portrait or landscape orientation (specifically, whether height > width or not). On rotation, in `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:`, I update the constants of some auto layout constraints appropriately. The problem is that at this point the view's frame has not actually rotated yet, so I often get an angry message in the debugger that my constraints can't be satisfied.

**My question is this:** at what point in the rotation sequence do I modify constraints so that the view's frame has already changed, but I still get the animation alongside the rotation?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739902/ios-change-auto-layout-constraints-when-device-rotates) suggests calling `[self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints]` in `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation`, but that method is now deprecated. I tried calling that method in `viewWillTransitionToSize`, but still get the angry messages.

Comment: Is that iphone app or universal app ??? Because if you want to change the UI only for iphone in portrait and landscape mode make use of size classes buddy :) No need to add,modify or remove the constraint buddy :) you can handle all in story board itself

Comment: @SandeepBhandari this is a universal app, so there's no way to tell from size classes whether the iPad is in portrait or landscape.

Comment: What happens if the iPad is in landscape, and then the user activates a split screen?  Thinking about portrait vs landscape is no longer appropriate.  You need to start designing your interface around size classes.

Comment: @Curmudgeonlybumbly I know. I'm defining landscape as view width > view height. Size classes can't tell me that specifically. iPad fullscreen is regular size class in both directions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I appear to have solved it. See [this article](http://imnotyourson.com/ios-adaptive-layout-with-rotation-tips/) and [PureLayout](https://github.com/PureLayout/PureLayout). Basically:

- Implement a method something like `-(void)updateConstraintsForSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator;`
- In this method, if you've rotated (store the state somewhere), uninstall all your constraints and generate new ones. If you have a coordinator, install them and `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]` in the coordinator's `animateAlongsideTransition` block parameter. Otherwise just install and layout.
- Override `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and call this method with `self.view.bounds.size` and `nil`
- Override `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` and call your method appropriately